# reactjs: is there public API to check if the component is mounted/unmounted

Tags: reactjs

Basically I would like to have this within a component:

```
setTimeout(() =>
{
  if (this.isMounted())  // NOTE: this does not exist
    setState({ foo: 123 });
}, 5000);
```

But there is no API for that, am I wrong?

Calling `setState()` on an unmounted components is considered an error (and logged such one by React when in development mode).

Of course, I could set my own state in `componentWillUnmount()` by setting `this._mounted = false` and so on, but I don't like adding private state if not needed.

Comment: Did you check `componentDidMount` hook ? https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount

Comment: Some discussions are going on adding new life cycle hooks https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7678

Comment: I already know the components lifecycle, thanks anyhow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this is the exact scenario `isMounted()` was originally created for, the current recommendation the [**usage of `isMounted()` is bad and will be removed in future React versions**](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html).

Instead, you should just check that any asynchrous functions are properly cancelled upon unmounting the component. If you use `setTimeout`, it's easy enough to just save the timeout identifier and cancel it in `componentWillUnmount`:

```js
this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
  this.setState({ foo: 123 });
}, 5000);

...

componentWillUnmount() {
  clearTimeout(this.timeout)
}
```

So to answer your question, there is no and there should be no API for checking if a component is mounted. This is because when unmounted, all references to the component should be cleared so that the garbage collector may remove it from memory.

Comment: That's exactly what I don't want: keeping useless private properties in my components (`this.timer`) just to reference a dumb timer.

Thanks a lot for the link.

Comment: Basically Reactjs tells you to create your own `isMounted` private property/method instead of providing one. I don't like it because I consider `this.isMounted()` really useful (and not just due to a bad coding).

Comment: @Iñaki they're not useless - they have a clear purpose. If you find yourself adding these types of properties in many places, maybe you can make a reusable timer component.

Comment: @tom-fenech this is not about timers, but about any code that runs on callbacks based on network events. For example I may want to run a `XMLHttpRequest ` within a component, and ignore the HTTP 200 result if the component was unmounted before it happened.